# Find the segment $BQ$ in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: Let a circle $\omega$ (not labelled in the graph) centered at $P$ tangent to $AB$, and $T$ is point of tangency. $\angle APB=90^\circ$. Let $K$ (not labelled in the graph) be some point on the circle $\omega$, the semicircle with diameter $BK$ intersects $PB$ at $Q$. Let $R$ be the radius of that semi-circle. If $4R^2-AT\cdot TB=10$ and $PQ=\sqrt2$, calculate $BQ$.(Answer:$2\sqrt3$)

[image]

My progress:
$PT \perp AB\\
\triangle PTB:BT^2+PT^2 = PB^2\\
PT^2+AT^2=PA^2\\
PB=PQ+QB$
???....

Comment: Could you be more specified with the graph? What is $Q$ and what circle (I see a circle and a semi-circle, I believe it is the semi-circle) has radius $R$? I think you need other condition as well, for example, how the semi-circle is constructed?

Comment: @JetfiRex  The problem is exactly as in the book..The data is just this.

Comment: @JetfiRex  $Q$ for me is the intersection of the line $PB$ with the semicircle of radius $R$

Comment: Still not clear to me... Without knowing how the semicircle is constructed, I think $Q$ has no difference to a random point on $PB$...

Comment: @JetfiRex A colleague verified what was missing in this question in order to have a solution: the triangle APB is right at P

Comment: Ok, now we can solve it, and I edited the question to make it clearer. Does my edit correctly express the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Q$ be the intersection of semi-circle and $BP$, we have $KQ\perp BP$. So, we have $KP^2-BK^2=(KP^2-QK^2)-(BK^2-QK^2)=PQ^2-BQ^2$. Notice that $\angle APB=90^\circ$ and $TP\perp AB$, we have $KP^2=KT^2=AT\times TB$, and $BK^2=4R^2$. So we have $BQ^2=PQ^2+(BK^2-KP^2)=PQ^2+(4R^2-AT\times TB)=2+10=12$, thus $BQ=2\sqrt 3$.

Comment: Thansks for help

Comment: I didn't understand the point "K", intersection of semi-circle and "BP", "Q" would be the intersection of the semi-circle with "BP"???

Comment: @petaarantes Thanks for pointing out, I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

I found [JetfiRex’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4412255/160630) a little dense and hard to follow, so here’s how I approached it.

Add segments $\mathrm{PK}$, $\mathrm{PT}$, and $\mathrm{KQ}$ to the initial diagram, like so:

[image: A redrawn version of the diagram in the question, with additional segments marked.]

($\mathrm{PT} \perp \mathrm{AB}$ since they are a radius of and tangent to $\omega$, respectively, and $\mathrm{KQ} \perp \mathrm{PB}$ by Thales’ theorem.)

Also assign letters to the segment lengths as shown, for brevity. We wish to find length $x$, and we can express the given relationship as $4R^2 - pq = 10$, or better yet:
$$
\begin{align}
(2R)^2 &= pq + 10 \\
\therefore pq &= (2R)^2 - 10 \tag 1
\end{align}
$$

From $\triangle \mathrm{BKQ}$, we have $(2R)^2 = x^2 + y^2$, which we can substitute into (1) to obtain:
$$
pq = x^2 + y^2 - 10 \tag 2
$$

From $\triangle \mathrm{KPQ}$ and $\triangle \mathrm{APT}$, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
r^2 &= y^2 + 2 \tag 3 \\
    &= n^2 - p^2 \\
\therefore p^2 &= n^2 - y^2 - 2 \tag 4
\end{align}
$$

And from $\triangle \mathrm{BPT}$ and $\triangle \mathrm{ABP}$, we have:
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
(x + \sqrt{2})^2 &= q^2 + r^2 \\
                 &= (p + q)^2 - n^2 \\
\therefore n^2 + \cancel{q^2} + r^2 &= (p + q)^2 \\
    &= p^2 + 2pq + \cancel{q^2} \\
\therefore n^2 + r^2 &= p^2 + 2pq
\end{align}
$$

Substituting all of (2), (3) and (4) into this gives:
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\cancel{n^2} + \cancel{y^2} + 2 &= n^2 - y^2 - 2 + 2(x^2 + y^2 - 10) \\
    &= n^2 - y^2 - 2 + 2x^2 + 2y^2 - 20 \\
    &= \cancel{n^2} + 2x^2 + \cancel{y^2} - 22 \\
\therefore  2 &= 2x^2 - 22 \\
\therefore 2x^2 &= 24 \\
\therefore x \phantom{^2} &= \sqrt{12} = 2\sqrt{3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

$4R^2=10+AT.TB(I)\\
\triangle APB: PT^2=AT.TB(II)\\
\triangle PDQ: PD^2 = PQ^2+QD^2=(\sqrt2)^2+QD^2=2+QD^2 (III)\\
\triangle QBD: BD^2 = BQ^2+QD^2 \implies 4R^2 - BQ^2=QD^2(IV)\\
(II)em(I): 4R^2 = 10+\underbrace{PT}_{=PD}^2=10+PD^2=10+2+QD^2(V)\\
(III)em(V): 4R^2 = 12+4R^2-BQ^2\implies \boxed{BQ= \sqrt12 = 2\sqrt3}$

[image]